# Why is � not listed in the Windows character table?

Tags: unicode

So there is "�", the replacement character 0xFFFD, the symbol for a byte-sequence that is not represented as a character in Unicode (right?).

Well, I wonder what 'is' this 'thing' actually, as I can't 'see'/'find' it in Windows' character table, neither searching for the symbol itself, nor searching for FFFD. But after all it is a character, right? So it should be in there. I am confused ...

[image]

Comment: Did you try a different font? Although I guess Arial would have it.. EDIT: Guess it doesn't \/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font Arial does probably not contain a corresponding [glyph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glyph) to represent that character. Try a different font like Arial Unicode or [Arial Unicode MS](http://www.microsoft.com/typography/fonts/family.aspx?FID=24).

Comment: Ah okay, well I already tried further fonts. Kind of confusing as Arials Unicode character set seems to even include arabic chars. Hmmm ... Arial Unicode MS though represents this character.